# Raspberry Pi Information outside of the StackExchange scope?

Tags: discussion

See the question [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/is-there-a-canonical-resource-for-project-ideas).

I understand that raspberrypi.stackexchange.com is not the place to brag about your latest RPi hack.  I also understand that we don't want to fill the site with pages of links.

However, I attempted to ask a specific question about project design resources, and it was closed as not constructive.  This may have been about wording, so I'm heading to meta to get it sorted out.

What is the best way to ask for information about things that don't belong at this site, such as a canonical list of finished projects and project ideas, but may be canonically represented elsewhere on the internet in a single place?

Answer (score 3):

> What is the best way to ask for information about things that don't belong at this site, such as a canonical list of finished projects and project ideas, but may be canonically represented elsewhere on the internet in a single place?

Ask it in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3748/the-bakery). You can also brag in chat :P

> This may have been about wording, so I'm heading to meta to get it sorted out.

Yep, it may have been about wording. Just a note: adding "I don't want a list of links, just a single answer" doesn't make a list question into a non-list. Then you just make it a first-come-first-serve question.

---

This particular meta post doesn't seem to ask this, but it may be worthwile to hash out exactly what type of list questions are OK in a spearate metapost. Many sites have their own policies on these questions. Like [this policy for books questions on chem](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118/should-we-allow-books-questions).

Comment: Chat isn't searchable, is it?  I admit I'm not a big user of chat on the stackexchange sites.

Comment: @Zoot There is a search bar in the [chat] room at the top right.

Comment: @Zoot: It is. Top right corner, you can search. If you're talking about Googlability, chat is Googleable as well. Eg [this](http://www.google.co.in/search?q=Just+a+heads-up%3A+if+you're+flagging+%22see+this+answer%22+answers%2C+you+can+save+the+mods+handling+these+a+bit+of+time+by+flagging+the+question+with+a+l)

Comment: Good to know.  I thought chat was for when you wanted to go "off record".

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm concerned, this is on topic.

Yes, it's asking for a link to an external repository - but it's not asking for the *best* repository, or even a link to several external repositories, it's simply asking if there is one that exists, which in my mind is a perfectly valid question.

After a quick search I couldn't see one either. Now it may be (in fact I can see it easily being the case) that a few months down the line one may well appear, or several may appear, which would then I think be a valid reason to close said question as too localised.

You see lots of valid, open questions on SO asking for particular hard to find libraries for languages; I don't see how this is hugely different.

Answer (score 1):

This question has now been reopened.

In it's original form the question was an example of *bad-subjective*, in that there was no definite answer. It also promoted link based short answers, which are not encouraged.

In it's current form the question has an identifyable answer, and is now *good-subjective*. In that it can be answered reasonably and remains useful for future visitors.

For more details, please refer to [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).

If anyone wishes to disagree with this decision please discuss in [The Bakery](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3748/the-bakery) or leave a comment.